# Wave readframes stackoverflow. Removing range

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have problem with reading big wave files.
Good code but range causes stackoverflow.

```
handle = wave.open('data_sylaby\s1.wav', 'r')
framerate = handle.getframerate();
nframes = handle.getnframes()

for i in range(handle.getnframes()):
        frame = handle.readframes(1)
        data = struct.unpack("<h", frame)
```

New code but it throws error that

> unpack requires a string argument of length 2

.
Second and third version throw this error but it should work like version with range.
I need to remove range because it eats me 10Gb of memory.

Error code:

```
    handle = wave.open('data_sylaby\s1.wav', 'r')
    framerate = handle.getframerate();
    nframes = handle.getnframes()
    i = 0
    while i  < nframes:
        frame = handle.readframes(1)
        data = struct.unpack("<h", frame)
        i = i + 1
```

Third version also Error:

```
for j in range(nframes/framerate + 1):
        for i in range(j *framerate, (j+1)*framerate):
            if i >= nframes:
                break
```

Comment: `data = pack('<' + ('h'*len(data)), *data)` That's what i use to pack the data, can you do something in reverse perhaps?

Comment: thx i need to fix unpack and replace range with xrange